# Limit Laws Questions (Multiplication)

Tags: limits

If lim f(x) (as x approaches 0) = x =0 and lim g(x) (as x approaches 0) = 1/x which DNE. Is lim f(x)g(x) = 1? Because if you separate can't it become lim f(x) multiply lim g(x) which is 0 multiply DNE and that doesn't equal one. My bad but I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: The limit law "the limit of a product is the product of the limits" only is allowed IF the individual limits exist (meaning not infinity). In your example, of course $x$ times $1/x$ is just $1$, but generally one cannot say $0$ times $infinity$ is $1$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_a(x) = ax$ and $g(x) = \frac1x$.

Then you have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} f_a(x) &= 0\\
\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) &= \infty\\
\lim_{x\to 0} f_a(x) g(x) &= \lim_{x\to 0} ax\,\frac1x = a.
\end{align}

This means “$0\cdot\infty$” can become any value and therefore has no real meaning.